# Would like to know why this query is behaving this way?

Tags: postgresql

I have an `emp` table, with schema and some initial values like below:

```
 emp_id | name | last_name | role_id 
--------+------+-----------+---------
      1 | hell | bell      |       1
      2 | well | tell      |       2
(2 rows)
```

And another `role` table, which `emp` table has referenced on `role_id`. 
Below is the `role` table:

```
 role_id | role_name 
---------+-----------
       1 | tech
       2 | op
       3 | dev
(3 rows)
```

I was just playing around, and wrote the below query, which I suppose don't make much sense.

```
SELECT emp.name, role.role_name, emp.emp_id 
FROM emp 
INNER JOIN role 
    ON emp.role_id = (
        SELECT role_id from role WHERE role_name = 'tech'
    );
```

It worked and returned this result:

```
 name | role_name | emp_id 
------+-----------+--------
 hell | tech      |      1
 hell | op        |      1
 hell | dev       |      1
(3 rows)
```

I would like to know why I'got this result and how it worked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query, given your data, is equivalent to this one:

```
SELECT emp.name, role.role_name, emp.emp_id 
FROM emp 
INNER JOIN role 
    ON emp.role_id = 1; -- because this is the role_id for 'tech'
```

This means that you don't define a condition about how to join the two tables.  In turn, this results in a Cartesian product of `role` (without any restriction about which rows to return) and `emp` (where `role_id` is 1).

Again rewriting the query, it is effectively a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT emp.name, role.role_name, emp.emp_id 
FROM emp 
CROSS JOIN role 
WHERE emp.role_id = 1;
```

See them on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/abcce/4).

What you possibly want is

```
SELECT emp.name, role.role_name, emp.emp_id 
FROM emp 
INNER JOIN role 
    ON emp.role_id = role.role_id
WHERE emp.role_id = 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

The sub-select:

```
SELECT role_id from role WHERE role_name = 'tech'
```

returns exactly one row, so your query can be transformed to:

```
SELECT emp.name, role.role_name, emp.emp_id 
FROM emp 
JOIN role 
    ON emp.role_id = 1
```

This can be transformed to:

```
SELECT emp.name, role.role_name, emp.emp_id 
FROM emp 
CROSS JOIN role 
WHERE emp.role_id = 1
```

Therefor the emp(s) with role_id = 1 (i.e. `hell bell`) is multiplied with all possible roles. Since there are three roles, you get three rows in the result.